# Can't get the correct value of closed integral with Green's Theorem, code just throws 0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm solving a closed integral but my code is not giving the correct output. The integral being $$\int_C = xy^2dy-4x\sin y dy$$

I'm using Green's Theorem and my code is the following:

```
L[x_, y_] := x*y^2
M[x_, y_] := -4*Sin[y]

region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && y < x^2, {x, y}]
NIntegrate[D[M[x, y], x] - D[L[x, y], y], {x, y} ∈ region]
```

This gives as output `0`but the real value is `2.0916`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `L[x_, y_] := x*y^2;
M[x_, y_] := -4*x*Sin[y];
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && y < x^2, {x, y}]
NIntegrate[D[M[x, y], x] - D[L[x, y], y], {x, y} ∈ region]`

Comment: $\int_{C}xy^2 \,\mathrm{d}x-4x\sin y \,\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: There's a typo in the definition of `M[x_, y_]`: You forgot an `x`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want to calculate
$$\int_{C}xy^2 \,\mathrm{d}x-4x\sin y \,\mathrm{d}y$$
Where $C$ is the boundary of region.

```
L[x_, y_] := x*y^2;
M[x_, y_] := -4*x*Sin[y];
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && y < x^2, {x, y}];
NIntegrate[D[M[x, y], x] - D[L[x, y], y], {x, y} ∈ region]
```

> `2.09163`